# How to count data occurrence in a MySQL table using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I want to count the number of times for example John have worked for 5 hours from Date 2012-01-01 to 2012-01-25.

```
DATE      | Name | Hours Worked |
---------------------------------
2012-01-25| John | 5            |
2012-01-25| Bob  | 3            |
2012-01-26| John | 6            |
2012-01-27| Bob  | 7            |
```

I am a bit new to php any help most welcome.

Comment: google basic select queries on the net and try to learn them.

Comment: The way SO works is you first try to solve the problem yourself and then, when you hit something you don't understand, you ask a specific question.  It appears you haven't tried any research on MySQL queries (the question has nothing to do with PHP).  Please read the [faq] and [ask] to understand how SO works.

Comment: any effort from your side is most welcome. If you are new to php then best way to start is to read the documentation. It doesnt matter how simple/basic/silly question you ask, but it does matter if you expect someone to do it for.

Comment: check my answer and let me know if this is what you were looking for...

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE Name = 'John' AND Hours = '5' AND Date > '2012-01-01' AND Date < 2012-01-25
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(Name) FROM table WHERE Date >= '2012-01-01' AND Date <= '2012-01-25' AND Name = 'John' AND HoursWorked = '5'
```

That should do it.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you are using a localhost like "wamp/xamp" and your database name is test and your table name is user, then follow the below code and you will get your answer.

First go to your localhost/phpmyadmin then create a database "test", the write the below code on sql window

```
CREATE TABLE user(`date` DATE NOT NULL ,`name` VARCHAR( 60 ) NOT NULL ,`hour_worked` INT NOT NULL ,`id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,PRIMARY KEY ( `id` ))ENGINE = MYISAM ;
```

then insert the values into that table. Now write the below code in a php page and save it on your folder suppose folder name "test".

```
<?php
$host="localhost";
$user="root";
$pass="";
$db="test";
$con=@mysql_connect($host,$user,$pass);
mysql_select_db($db);

$sql="SELECT * FROM user WHERE name='John'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
$row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
echo $row["name"]."&nbsp;have worked for&nbsp;". $row["hour_worked"]."&nbsp;from Date&nbsp;".$row["date"];?>
```

now run the code using your localhost and you'll get it.
Nice try keep it up!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want number of hours worked between two dates. If YES, Below will give you what you want...

```
SELECT sum(hours_column), Name FROM table WHERE Date >= '2012-01-01' AND Date <= '2012-01-25' AND Name = 'John'
```

If you want to see for all employees use below

```
SELECT sum(hours_column), Name FROM table WHERE Date >= 'start_date' AND Date <= 'end_date' GROUP BY Name
```